# Как отфильтровать элементы яндекс карты по их вхождению в видимую область?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем привет! У сайта есть страница контактов, на ней отображается карта с филиалами и партнёрами компании. Данные по филиалам и партнёрам приходят в JSON объекте.

Добавляю я их на карту вот таким образом:

```js
      $.each(jsonData, function (index, element) {

            //Рисуем шаблон для элемента карты
            layout = drawPartner(element);
            myBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                layout,
                {
                    build: function () {
                        this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);
                        this.$element = $(this.getParentElement()).find('.office');
                        this._applyElementOffset();
                        this.$element.parent().find('.js-info-window-close').on('click',                        $.proxy(this._onCloseButtonClick, this));
                    },
                    clear: function () {
                        this.$element.find('.close').off('click');
                        this.constructor.superclass.clear.call(this);
                    },
                    /**
                     * Сдвигаем балун чтобы "хвостик" указывал на точку привязки.
                     * @see http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/IBalloonLayout.xml#event-userclose
                     * @function
                     * @private
                     * @name applyElementOffset
                     */
                    _applyElementOffset: function () {
                        this.$element.css({left: - (this.$element[0].offsetWidth / 1.95), top: (this.$element[0].offsetHeight * 0.69)});
                    },
                    _onCloseButtonClick: function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('.js-tabs-body').removeClass('hidden'); //Показываем список элементов
                        this.events.fire("userclose");
                    }
                }
            );

            var Point = new ymaps.Placemark([element.lat, element.lon], {
                name: element.name,
                partnamane: element.partnamane,
                partcolor: element.partcolor,
                partsign: element.partsign,
                type: element.type,
                address: element.address,
                siteLink: element.siteLink,
                pageLink: element.pageLink,
                file: element.file,
                tel: element.tel,
                type: element.type,
                props: element.props,
                icon: element.icon,
                icon_hover: element.icon_hover
            }, {
                balloonContent: '<div>***</div>',
                balloonContentLayout: myBalloonLayout,
                balloonOffset: [0, 0],
                balloonCloseButton: false,
                iconImageHref: server + element.icon,  //Путь к картинке точки
                iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
                iconImageSize: [40, 40],
                iconImageOffset: [-0, -0],
                balloonShadow: false,
            });

            Point.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
                $('.js-tabs-body').addClass('hidden'); //Скрываем список элементов
            });

            clusterer.add(Point);
        });

        partnersMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
```

Всё работает отлично, карта создаётся, кластеры и точки устанавливаются http://joxi.ru/krDpEXRIE11PLr балун отрисовывается как надо http://joxi.ru/Drlae4BuvMMW3m.

Но, мне при клике на кластер, нужно получить только те элементы, которые есть в момент "открытия" кластера в видимой области карты. Это нужно для перестройки вот этого списка http://joxi.ru/1A5bnPGInooqpr отдельно висящего над картой.

И вроде бы нашёл решение https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/55186, т.е. проверить состояние объекта через getObjectState , но возникли вопросы. Как я понимаю чтобы воспользоваться этим примером https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__getObjectState мне нужно добавить точки на карту не так как сейчас, а как показано тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager , т.е. через objectManager. Но не ясно вот что, при таком добавлении метод objectManager.add(data) принимает JSON в определённом формате как показано в песочнице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager ?  Можно ли добавлять объекты так, чтобы сохранить свой уникальный внешний вид балуна (это важно по дизайну)? Как добавлять прослушку событий на точки при таком добавлении их на карту (пример одного из событий за которым я слежу:

```js
            Point.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
                $('.js-tabs-body').addClass('hidden'); //Скрываем список элементов
            });
```

)?

И ещё, правильно ли я понимаю, что для фильтрации элементов по видимой области карты, нужно прослушивать клик по кластеру

```js
clusterer.events.add('click', function () { ... }
```

или нужно "слушать" что-то другое?

Comment: У кластера тоже есть этот метод: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#method_detail__getObjectState "Но, мне при клике на кластер, нужно получить только те элементы, которые есть в момент "открытия" кластера в видимой области карты. Это нужно для перестройки вот этого списка http://joxi.ru/1A5bnPGInooqpr отдельно висящего над картой." Нужно получить все элементы которые есть на карте или все элементы кластера которые есть на карте?

Comment: @se0ga Все элементы которые есть в видимой области карты, ну да в общем все элементы которые входят в кластер по которому кликнул посетитель, по идеи только они и будут показаны на карте.

Comment: Ну тогда попробуйте слушать событие клика по кластеру и получать все элементы этого кластера в момент клика.